# Tips or resources for learning advanced debugging techniques GDB in xcode

Tags: xcode, gdb

Can someone recommend some good tips or resources to learn how to learn intermediate to advanced debugging tips and tricks using GDB in Xcode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GDB in XCode is essentially normal GDB with some GUI wrappers for common operations (next, skip, finish etc.), so any general GDB information will still be applicable.

[Debugging with GDB](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html) is a pretty comprehensive book which is available online, and is pretty much the main reference document.